# How to add documentation to cloned R repository

Tags: r, github, repository, rstudio, code-documentation

I am currently working on a private data repository on GitHub, but keep running into an issue with the documentation that comes up when searching ??myRepository.

I have a folder called man in my data repository that stores all the .Rd files that show up on the help(myRepository), and have 2 .Rmd files in my vignette folder that I would like to add to the documentation in .Rd format.

I have two questions:

1. How to I convert .Rmd files into .Rd files?
2. Is there a way I can override the automatically generated .Rd files and upload my own documentations using the Rmd files in my vignette folder?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Since you have .Rd files, are you making a package? If so I'd recommend using `roxygen2`. If you are already using this package already, I've only seen people make and document their functions in `.R` files. And finally, can you be more specific about the exact issue you are running into?

Comment: Yes, I am making it into a data package. My issue is that I already have the documentation created in .Rmd format, but that's not showing up when I search up my package using help().  I need the .Rmd files in the vignettes folder to be re-created as .Rd files in my man folder